# multi addresses

Tags: web3js, nodejs

how can i send to account2,account3 and account4 in one time transaction

```
var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx')

const Web3 = require('web3')
const web3 = new Web3('https://ropsten.infura.io')

const account1 = '0x9c56......'

const account2 = '0xb22.....'

const account3 = '0x7717d10.......'

const account4 = '0xdt7d10.......'


const privateKey1 = Buffer.from('bla bla bla', 'hex')

web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account1, (err, txCount) => {

const txObject = {
  nonce: web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
  to: account2,
  value: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('0.1', 'ether')),
  gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(21000),
  gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('10', 'gwei'))
}

const tx = new Tx(txObject)
tx.sign(privateKey1)

const serializedTx = tx.serialize()
const raw = '0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex')

web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(raw, (err, txHash) => {
  console.log('txHash:', txHash)
  // Now go check etherscan to see the transaction!
})
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Transactions are only sent with from single source address to single destination address.

To send multiple transactions , create as many transactions as destinations accounts you have, in a loop.

Or, you can create a contract for this task and send single transaction to a contract, which is going to send as many transfers as required, using destination addresses you are going to pass to it on input parameter.

Comment: please show me example how to make a looping from that script